# Error while editing SP : Could not add Service Provider. You might be entering a duplicate Service Provider

Tags: wso2, service-provider, wso2-identity-server

We are getting following error when we try to edit service provider: `Could not add Service Provider. You might be entering a duplicate Service Provider`

Steps Followed

1. Created service provider
2. Trying to update `Inbound Authentication Configuration` --> `SAML2 Web SSO Configuration` --> `Configure`
3. Update

We are using version wso2is-5.1.0.

[image: Eror: Screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of WSO2 you are using, this was a bug that infrequently came up when the entry for the SAML provider persisted after the Service Provider that used it was deleted. There's a URL that is not documented in the interface where you can fix this. After logging into the interface, go to this URL:

https://yourhost:yourport/carbon/sso-saml/manage_service_providers.jsp

and you should be able to delete the offending SAML provider and configure the service provider.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  We have   accessed  Manage  service provider page and  we don't see the  particular entry.  Also we have added  new SP entire and  new SP entire present in manage service provide page.    So where we can see list of SP entires created or updated or deleted ?     We are using version wso2is-5.1.0.